# C++ 2d unordered_map with vector

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, unordered-map

im coming from PHP where i would do

```
$um['Im a string'][1] = 3;
```

for a 2d associative array where the first key is a string, the second an integer and the value is an integer as well. I try to do the same in c++. here is my attempt:

```
// experiment.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::unordered_map;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    unordered_map <string,vector<int,int>> um;

    um["Im a string"][1] = 3;
    printf("Out: %d", um["Im a string"][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

obviously its not the right syntax;

Comment: `test.cc:4:20: fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory`.  Was that your problem?

Comment: @Zack stdafx.h is an auto-generated file in MSVS. (extra hint is _tmain). The problem is `vector<int,int>`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I guessed as much, but I don't like to assume. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<int,int>` isn't correct (`vector` isn't an associative container), you probably want a nested `unordered_map<int>`. So:

```
unordered_map <string,unordered_map<int,int>> um;
```

Comment: Don't you need two template arguments to the inner `unordered_map`?  Also I'm pretty sure this isn't the *only* problem with this code.

Comment: @Zack oh, yeah, that's what I meant to do  :)

Comment: yes, unordered_map <string,unordered_map<int, int>> um; worked. u have to give two arguments as Zack pointed out.

Comment: @user1748124 yeah, I know, that was a mistake done by haste :)

Comment: do i have any other choice in c++ if i want ot represent this sructure? (2d key1:string key2 int value int)

Comment: @user1748124 yes. You can use a simple `std::map` instead of `unordered_map`, or you can implement your own container and overload `operator[]`.